# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\arcsin(3^{-n})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I have been working on this question for two days,

does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\arcsin(3^{-n})$ converge?

---

I did that.
$$\arcsin x<\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ then i put $3^{-n}$ as $x$ , $3^{-n}\in (0,1]$

$$\arcsin(3^{-n})<\frac{3^{-n}}{\sqrt{1-(3^{-n})^2}}$$
$$\arcsin(3^{-n})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{(3^{2n})-1}}$$

then I use  limit comparasion test.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2n}-1}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2n}}}}=1$$
then
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2n}-1}}$ converges since also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2n}}}$ is converges by geometric series

---

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2n}-1}}$ converges then also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3^n}\right)$ converges

---

I have completed the assigned tasks; however, I am uncertain about the accuracy of all methodologies employed. Furthermore, I am seeking clarification on whether there exists a more straightforward approach to address the question."

Comment: In a neighboutrhood of complex $z=0$, 

 $$\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)+\sin^{-1}(y) = x \sqrt{1-x^2} + y \sqrt{1-y^2} $$  

so the question is about the convergence of 

$$\sum 3^{-n}\sqrt{1-3^{-2n}}$$

Comment: From the taylor series
$$
\arcsin x =
x+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{3}{40}x^5+\frac{5}{112}x^7+\frac{35}{1152}x^9+...
$$


The numerical value is
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{6\times 3^{3n}}+\frac{3}{40\times 3^{5n}}+\frac{5}{112\times 3^{7n}}+...
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\ge 0}
\frac{3}{3-1}+\frac{27}{6\times (27-1)}+\frac{3\times 243}{40\times (243-1)}+\frac{5\times 2187}{112\times (2187-1)}+...
$$
$$
\approx 2.077538604616959148903156...
$$

Answer (score 1):

For large enough $n$ you can see $$\arcsin(\frac 1{3^n}
)\sim \frac 1{3^n}$$
but to make sure of comparison you can use for example below inequality
$$0\leq \arcsin(\frac 1{3^n}) <
 \frac 2{3^n}$$and  $$\sum \frac 2{3^n}=\frac {\frac 13}{1-\frac 23}$$